# Python Multi-Threaded Logging

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I'm trying to write a simple port-checking program that tests VMware Horizon network ports. The port-checking itself is working just fine, but my "multi-threaded" logging is falling short between lines 71 and 91. I know for a fact I'm doing this wrong because I piecemeal-ed the logging portion together from multiple posts online. I have no experience with running loggers and my Python is intermediate on my best day. Anyway, can someone help me clean up the logging portion and make it work as expected?

I'm running the port checks in multiple threads for speed, and subsequently I want to accurately log the results of each thread. I had this working for a while, I think, but I made some modifications to the beginning of my logging code to "clean" it up and I broke something. Unfortunately I didn't have this in a git repo at the time, so I can't revert my changes any longer. If you can, please give me as much detail about how to fix/re-write the logging portion to accomplish clean multi-threaded logging. I'd even be interested in keeping the threaded logging grouped together for readability, but that's not a must. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here's an example of the error being thrown and the entire sanitized code is below that.

> **The error message:**

```
THREAD INFORMATION PRINT
<Worker(Thread-1, initial)>
THREADRESULT IS:
None
logging_threads is:
[<Worker(Thread-1, started 140445767894784)>]
INFO    : pod1.azvd.private.example.com # Checking port: 80 on pod1.azvd.private.example.com
INFO    : pod1.azvd.private.example.com # Checking port: 443 on pod1.azvd.private.example.com
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "./horizon_troubleshooter.py", line 41, in run
    self.logger.info('Created Log for {}'.format(self.info['pod_name']))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1455, in info
    self.logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'
```

> **The full code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# VMware Horizon troubleshooter
# Test port connectivity and call
# and response, then output to file.

import sys
import logging
import socket
import time
import threading
import traceback
from contextlib import closing

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format= '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s: %(thread)x -- %(pod_name)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d # %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/tmp/horizon-troubleshooter.log',
                    filemode='w')

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s: %(pod_name)-12s # %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger = logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.running=False
        self.info=info
        self.logger=logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, self.info)
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
    def start(self):
        self.running=True
        super(Worker, self).start()
    def stop(self):
        self.running=False
    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.logger.info('Created Log for {}'.format(self.info['pod_name']))
            time.sleep(0.5)

def check_port(host, port):
    try:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(host) # get IP address of host
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # TCP
        #sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2.0) # floating integer for seconds
        result = sock.connect_ex((host,port))
        if result == 0:
            logging.info('Port: %s OPEN', port, extra={'pod_name': host})
            return True
        else:
            logging.info('Port: %s CLOSED', port, extra={'pod_name': host})
            return False
        sock.close()
        logging.debug('Result: %s for port check on: %s', result, port, extra={'pod_name': host}) 
    except:
        logging.error('check_port failed for %s', port, extra={'pod_name': host })

# set variables for ports and hosts to check
port_list = [80, 443, 4172, 8443]
domain_name = ".azvd.private.example.com"
hostname_prefix = "pod"
num_pods = 22
logging_threads = []
max_threads = 50    # maximum thread count for multi-threaded port check

# iterate through pods and test ports
for pod_num in range(1, num_pods + 1):
    try:
        pod_name = (hostname_prefix + str(pod_num) + domain_name)
        logging.debug('PODNAME IS %s', pod_name, extra={'pod_name': pod_name})
        kwargs = ({'pod_name': pod_name})
        logging.debug('KWARGS is %s', kwargs, extra=kwargs)
        thread = Worker({'pod_name': pod_name})
        print("THREAD INFORMATION PRINT")
        print(thread)
        threadresult = thread.start()
        print('THREADRESULT IS:')
        print(threadresult)
        logging_threads.append(thread)
        print('logging_threads is: ')
        print(logging_threads)
        logging.debug("Thread started and appended to logging_threads", extra=kwargs)
    except NameError:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        lines = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        logging.error('\nFailed to create logging thread on %s', pod_name, extra=kwargs)
        logging.exception("exception data: %s", lines, extra=kwargs)

    for port in port_list:
        try:
            logging.info('Checking port: %s on %s', port, pod_name, extra={'pod_name': pod_name})
            threading.Thread(target=check_port, args=[str(pod_name), port]).start()
        except:
            logging.error('PORT_LIST FOR-LOOP FAILURE', extra={'pod_name': pod_name})

    while threading.active_count() > max_threads :
        time.sleep(2)

for lt in logging_threads:
    lt.stop()
for lt in logging_threads:
    lt.join()
```

Comment: I have not a clue of what line 70 would be since SO doesn't number code lines.

Also be aware that python can't run in parallel by using multiple threads, I strongly recommend that you use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Comment: To help people to help you 

* Share the error that you're facing
* If not facing any error share the behavior that you expect and what you get instead
* Reduce your problem to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not sure why  I got down-voted. I thought I included all the possible information and even the resolution to my problem. What more can I do? should I just remove my post altogether? I'm not trying to cause any issues or do something wrong. I just haven't used this site prior to writing an answer for a question a few months ago.

Comment: @WilliamSmyth If you have found a solution then you should post it in the answers section, please read [ask] and [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I never managed to get the logging to be cleaner, by say grouping the log output from each thread in the log file, but this wasn't a show stopper for me. I did, however, get the app to work without error. The fix for this error, that my OP was trying to solve:

**Error**

> ```py
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
>    self.run()
>  File "./horizon_troubleshooter.py", line 41, in run
>    self.logger.info('Created Log for {}'.format(self.info['pod_name']))
>  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1455, in info
>    self.logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs) 
>  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'
> ```

The solution was to make a small change to the statements referring to the variable assignment for the logger. The change is highlighted in the below code snippets.

**Broken Code**

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format= '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s: %(thread)x -- %(pod_name)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d # %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/tmp/horizon-troubleshooter.log',
                    filemode='w')

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s: %(pod_name)-12s # %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger()                        # here is where the problem starts
logger = logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)  # here is where the problem ends
```

**Corrected Code**

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-8s: %(thread)x -- %(pod_name)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d # %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/home/gecko/Desktop/horizon-troubleshooter.log',
                    filemode='w')

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s: %(pod_name)-12s # %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)     # **Here is the correction**
```

Long story short, I was reassigning my `logger` variable with the last statement in the broken code. All I wanted to do was add a second output for my log writes (i.e. the console), and all I needed to do was change the last line of code as shown in the 'Corrected Code' section above.